# How can I save the eigenvalues of a 1000x1000 COE matrix and 500x500 COE matrix in the same file?

Tags: export, csv-format

I have generated eigenvalues of '1' 1000x1000 matrix of `CircularOrthogonalEnsemble` and saved it in a csv file using `Export`. Now I want to save eigenvalues of another '1' 500x500 matrix of COE in the same csv file. How can I do that? In total, I want 100 csv files of eigenvalues combining eigenvalues of both the 500x500 matrix and  the 1000x1000 matrix

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler example, I have two lists: the first one has integers and the second one has real numbers in arrays of different sizes.

```
alist = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 10}];
blist = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}];
```

Let's say you have written a csv file using:

```
fName = "C:\\test.csv";
Export[fName, alist, "CSV"]
```

You can now open the file for appending as a stream first.

```
strm = OpenAppend[fName]
Export[strm, blist, "CSV"]
```

Don't forget to close the stream.

```
Close[strm]
```

[image]

To import back in Mma:

```
clist = Import[fName, "CSV"]
clist // TableForm
```